# Limit inferior, weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about weak convergence and limit inferior.

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space (if necessary $\sigma$-finite measure space). Let $(u_{t})_{t >0}$ be a family of square integrable  functions (i.e. for every $t>0$, $u_{t} \in L^{2}(\mu)$) . **Furthermore we suppose** $\displaystyle \sup_{t>0}\|u_{t}\|_{L^{2}(\mu)}<\infty$ i.e. $(u_{t})_{t>0}$ is $L^{2}(\mu)$-bounded

**Definition**

$u \in L^{2}(\mu)$ is called a weak limit of $(u_{t})_{t>0}$ if there exists a sequence $(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$ such that $u_{t_{n}}  \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow u$ weakly in $L^{2}(\mu)$

**Question**

Let $v$ is a square integrable function such that for every weak limit $u$ of $(u_{t})_{t>0}$, $v \leq u$ $\mu$-a.e. **Then can we show that for all nonnegative square integrable function** $\phi$,
\begin{align*}
 (v,\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} \leq \varliminf_{t \to 0} (u_{t},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)}
\end{align*}
Where
\begin{align*}
\varliminf_{t \to 0} (u_{t},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)}
=\sup_{\delta>0} \inf_{0<t<\delta} (u_{t},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)}
\end{align*}

**Attempt**

Let $(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence which converges to $0$. Since $(u_{t_{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is $L^{2}(\mu)$ bounded, we can find subsequence  of $(u_{t_{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $u \in L^{2}(\mu)$ such that $u_{t_{n_{k}}}  \underset{k \to \infty}\longrightarrow u$ weakly in $L^{2}(\mu)$. Therefore for all nonnegative $\phi \in L^{2}(\mu)$,
\begin{align*}
 (v,\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} &\leq (u,\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} \\
&\leq  \lim_{k \to \infty} (u_{t_{n_{k}}},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} \\
&\left(= \varliminf_{k \to \infty} (u_{t_{n_{k}}},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} \right)
\end{align*}
But $\displaystyle \varliminf_{t \to 0} (u_{t},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} \leq \varliminf_{k \to \infty} (u_{t_{n_{k}}},\phi)_{L^{2}(\mu)} $ . Please tell me what I should do.

Thank you in agvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the other way round. If $j_\phi = \varliminf_{t \to 0} (u_t, \phi)_{L^2}$, then you
can find a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (depending on $\phi$), such that $j_\phi = \lim_{n \to \infty} (u_{t_n}, \phi)_{L^2}$.

This should help you to write down a proof.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood. Your explanation is very clear!